# Простой и надежный метод бэкапа

Tags: резервное-копирование, debian, linux

Нужен метод для бэкапа сервера на Debian. Сейчас используется cron-скрипт, который периодически выполняет rsync на удаленную машину. Если ли метод лучше?

Answer (score 1):

В целом rsync очень даже неплох. Но вполне разумно использовать скрипты-обертки. Например, [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) (написан целиком на Perl). Почитать о нем можно там: [настройка резервного копирования в Ubuntu](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/linux/45912/#habracut).

При этом подход практически тот же: добавление cron-скрипта, который регулярно делает бэкап rsnapshot'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path_to_backup_storage/storage.bu
```

имя устройства, естественно, надо поставить своё. В результате будет создана копия файла устройства.

Answer (score 0):

Также если файлов не очень много, то tar'ить и отправлять одним файлом храниться на удаленный сервер